# Why does my item name not show up in 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in 1.13 Pre-Release 7 trying to make a one command creation and I need an item with a specific name. The command I use is `/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"Sword of Power"}}` and it gives my a diamond sword, but it doesn't have the name.

[image: This is me trying the command] This is me running the command.

[image: This is the command not working] This is the command not working.

Comment: 1.13 has made many things JSON. I'm currently not on my computer, can you try this? `/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"\"text\":\"Sword of Power\""}}` or maybe this: `/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Sword of Power\"}"}}`

Comment: THANK YOU @FabianRöling! Than means I can change the color of the text! THANK YOU AGAIN!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 1.13 many things are JSON that were previously just simple strings. So the syntax is now:

```
give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Sword of Power\"}"}}
```

This also means that you can colour the text, make it underlined, translatable, obfuscated, etc.

With Minecraft 1.14, support for single-quoted strings has now been added. This means that you can shorten JSON strings by surrounding them in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes:

```
give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:'{"text":"Sword of Power"}'}}
```

Whenever an NBT check doesn't work like you expected, I always recommend `/data get`. For example in this case you can hold the item and run:

```
/data get entity @s SelectedItem
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for this please?

Comment: The Minecraft wiki (and my memory) is my main source for everything: Here are the pages for the [`/give` command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/give) and for [JSON formatting](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Raw_JSON_text).

Comment: Archive links for my last comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Commands/give&oldid=1246312 and https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Commands&oldid=1260893#Raw_JSON_text

Answer (score 2):

In 1.14 and above, putting JSON text components into NBT string tags has been made a lot easier.
Instead of having to escape every `"` with a `\`, surround the entire NBT tag string with single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`. This means you can freely include double quotes in your string without having to escape them. This will mean that you will need to escape every single quote though, but there will not be that many single quotes in your JSON text component unless you explicitly need them.

Note that a single-quoted string with the same text as a double quoted string count as aliases and are equivalent to each other. Single quoted strings are now the default for all NBT string tags that involve JSON text elements. This is evident because using `/data get` will show the `Name` tag as a single-quoted string, no matter whether it was set using a single or double quoted string.

Here is the 1.14 way to give yourself that sword:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:'{"text":"Sword of Power"}'}}
```

Notice the use of single quotes to surround the string in `Name` instead of using double quotes. This will make creating JSON text in NBT much easier!

Answer (score 1):

It's `/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"\"Sword of Power\""}}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will make my commanding easier.

Comment: Why did you just copy my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:\"text\":\"Sword of Power\"}}
```

or if you want red color:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:\"text\":\"Sword of Power\",\"color\":\"red\"}}
```