# How do you put a lore on an item using commands in 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, to put a Lore on an object, it used to simply be:

```
{display:{Lore:["Example"]}}
```

Then they changed it to something else in version 1.14. What tag format do I put to receive an item with a lore? The command would be something like this:

```
/give (Selector) (item)({NBT_Tag}) (Count)
```

Here is an example with 2 unbreakable diamond axes given to the nearest player:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_axe{Unbreakable:1} 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft 1.13 display:{Name:""} NBT tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/minecraft-1-13-displayname-nbt-tag)

Comment: @pppery Same solution, completely different question. So nope, not a duplicate.

Comment: It has long been established consensus on this site that two questions requesting help debugging commands that turn out to have the same problem are considered duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

/give @p stick{display:{Lore:["\"lore!\""]}}

Comment: Dose this work in bedrock

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create colored or formatted text on the lore, use this instead:

```
/give @p stick{display:{Lore:[{"color":"red","text":"stick"}]}}
```

If you want to add more text just add more `{}` formats inside of the `Lore:[]` tag.