# Can't set the display name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to update the commands on a map to 1.13, every time I try to add a team with `/team add Green Creeper Corp` it wont accept the display name. I can use `/team add Green`, but I would like the name of Creeper Corp. I keep getting this error:

> Invalid chat component: Use JSONReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $[0] ...add Green [Creeper Corp]<--[HERE]

Is there a way to get it to accept the display name? and if so how?

Comment: Wow, that's a really bad error message. Basically tells you nothing about what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft 1.13 display:{Name:""} NBT tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/minecraft-1-13-displayname-nbt-tag)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate.  Find me a more generic string parsing in 1.13+ question, and I'll happily close both to that, but these two are otherwise completely unrelated.

Answer (score 9):

1.13 changed how you set display names. They must now be made with a json text component. For example:

```
team add Green {"text":"Creeper Corp"}
```

It's better this way, because now you can do stuff to the display name that you previously couldn't do. For example:

```
team add Green {"text":"Creeper ","color":"green","bold":"true","extra":[{"text":"Corp","color":"gold","italic":"true","underlined":"true"}]}
```

In the case of `/team`, you can also use a regular quoted string as a shortcut:

```
team add Green "Creeper Corp"
```

Answer (score 6):

JSON is very picky about input. It expects Strings to be enclosed in "".

You can use `/team add Green "Creeper Corp"` to add your team.

[image]