# Unable to use the /tag command to tag if wielding a specific item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Me and my friends have been creating a Minecraft realm, and I figured that I would make custom bosses and custom drops to spice up the game a bit. 
I've just got to a weapon that I'm trying to cause wither in other players when it hits, but first to do that I'm trying to tag the wielder. I wrote the command
`/tag @e[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Sword of Iapetos"}}}}] add IapetosSword`

For some reason though, whenever I hold the sword, it doesn't tag me! I assume I wrote the code wrong, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set the display name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346118/cant-set-the-display-name)

Comment: @ppery why would we close a question as a duplicate of a closed question?

Comment: @Penguin Because the question wasn't closed at the time I made that flag. What happened here is that I was searching for duplicate questions, found [Can't set the display name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/346118/185203), flagged this as duplicate, and then later found an even older question that both this and that questions were duplicates of. This should now be closed as a duplicate of [Minecraft 1.13 display:{Name:“”} NBT tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334946/185203), but users with <3k rep can't flag the same question for closure more than once.

Comment: @pppery oh, sorry didn't realise the time stamp because I thought it had happened a few hours ago

Answer (score 1):

NBT checks must be exact and item names are JSON, not simple strings. So instead of …

```
"Sword of Iapetos"
```

… check for:

```
"{\"text\":\"Sword of Iapetos\"}"
```

Or alternatively:

```
'{"text":"Sword of Iapetos"}'
```

You can find out things like this easily by running this command:

```
/data get entity @s SelectedItem
```