# Can I remove the shadow on an item's name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Java Minecraft 1.13, I'm trying to */give* an item with a custom name and color, but when I view it in the hotbar the text has a shadow effect that isn't present when I hover over it in the inventory. I've looked at most of the links on [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/minecraft-1-13-displayname-nbt-tag) page and the wiki pages, but I still don't really understand how the *Name:{}* tag works. If someone could explain if it is possible to turn off the shadow and how to do so that would be very helpful. Here is the give command I'm using:

```
give @p minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:flame",lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Fire Wand\",\"color\":\"orange\"}",Lore:["Hot Stuff!"]}} 1
```

I notice that the normal non-named items have no shadow, such as the one in the image from the above linked post, so there's probably some tag I'm missing. I've tried making it bold, italicized, and both, but it still has a shadow. Here's an example of the shadow I'm talking about:
[image: Shadowed item name.]

Comment: The name in the image in the post you linked has a shadow.

Comment: There's also no JSON tag for this.

Comment: Oh. It seems to have less of a shadow, maybe because it's not italicized, so I'll just use normal straight font.

Comment: I can't check it right now, but does the "clamp" option here help you? https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Resource_pack

Comment: I just checked it and no, it doesn't. This property can only be applied to "enchanted_item_glint", "pumpkinblur", "shadow" and "vignette". And "shadow.png" seems to be the entity shadow, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow is applied dynamically, so the only way to remove it would be a mod.

Comment: Do you know what types of situations cause it to be applied? Is it the block you are on, the actual characters you use, or something else?

Comment: Nothing, all text does this, at least all item switch name indicator thingies.

Answer (score 1):

The shadow is applied for all instances when seeing an item name. But when seeing an entity with a name the shadow will disappear, but this is unfortunately a server-side occurrence instead of a client-side occurrence unless you glitch the game.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly has a italics in it, so maybe you could try this?

```
give @p wooden_pickaxe{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"no italics!\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"},Unbreakable:true}
```