# 1.14.2 Weapon and armor Generation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i'm in minecraft 1.14.2 and i need to know how to make armor and weapons with descriptions and custom enchantments, can someone give me tips or a blank template for making armor and weapons. Please, i need to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are online easy-to-use command generators, for this purpose I used [minecraftcommand.science](https://minecraftcommand.science/armor-generator).

Because this command generator is a bit outdated for now, we are going to take two steps to achieve our goal: generating the command, and converting it into 1.13+ format.

Let's say I want a golden helmet with the name "Welcome to Arqade", lore (description) "Read the tour page" and second lore "Please", a `Thorns II` enchantment, and I want the helmet to be Unbreakable.

Here's the generated command from the [minecraftcommand.science](https://minecraftcommand.science/armor-generator) armor generator:

```
/give @p golden_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Welcome to Arqade",Lore:["Go read the tour page","Please"]},ench:[{id:7,lvl:2}],Unbreakable:1}
```

And here's the converted version:

```
/give @p golden_helmet{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Welcome to Arqade\"}",Lore:["Go read the tour page","Please"]},Enchantments:[{id:thorns,lvl:2}],Unbreakable:1}
```

First of all, the JSON formatting for `Name:"<name>"` has [changed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/minecraft-1-13-displayname-nbt-tag) in 1.13. Next up, the enchantment NBT formatting has changed from `ench:[{id:'numberID',lvl:'level'}]` to `Enchantments:[{id:'nameID',lvl:'level'}]`. Finally, the last change needed is putting the NBT before the item count in the command.

This is how the item looks in-game:

[image: Golden Helmet.]