# Hi. I need to figure out how to make a stick that has two specific NBT tags in Minecraft 1.15!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to figure out how to make a stick that has two specific NBT tags in Minecraft 1.15! I need it to be called "Box Breaker" and be only able to destroy brown Shulker boxes. I have no idea how to do it and I can't find it anywhere online. I have tried this but it won't give me the name (only the can destroy works).

`/give @p minecraft:stick{CanDestroy:   ["minecraft:stone"],display:{Name:"Box Breaker"}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my item name not show up in 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/why-does-my-item-name-not-show-up-in-1-13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten the escape sequences, you need forward slashes before and at the end of a string. Like this:

```
/give @p minecraft:stick{CanDestroy: ["minecraft:stone"],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Box Breaker\"}"}}
```

Or if you would not like the name to be italic:

```
/give @p minecraft:stick{CanDestroy: ["minecraft:stone"],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Box Breaker\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"}}
```

Comment: Thanks So much !! It works great :))) !!

Comment: @JudeSmy Thanks, I would appreciate it if you marked it as answer!