# How to give myself a dispenser to have a named bucket of Pufferfish

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm making a trap for a friend and I thought it would be easier to have a prefilled dispenser with the named bucket of pufferfish so yea, and I'll use this info for later for something else. Any suggestions would help.

The command I'm using is this, but I would check and the bucket of pufferfish isn't named.

```
/give Arjaysee dispenser 1 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:pufferfish_bucket,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"God"}}}]}}
```

So I was wondering if it was even possible.

Comment: Please review the following question for guidance: [Minecraft 1.13 display:{Name:""} NBT tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/minecraft-1-13-displayname-nbt-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue without commands. Place a dispenser with your named bucket of pufferfish inside of it. Then, `Ctrl + Middle Click` the dispenser. You will receive a dispenser block with an NBT tag identical to the dispenser you middle clicked.

Comment: Well what does `Middle Click` alone do?

Comment: @fasterthanlight It puts the block you middle clicked into your hand. Ctrl copies the nbt data, if any.

Comment: So does that mean that you can get a pitched noteblock from that (i.e. it copies its pitch, but not instrument)?

Comment: The pitch/note of noteblocks are not stored in nbt data, but rather as a block state. So, no.