# Please help with Minecraft Command to place dispenser pre-filled with pre-named items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The goal is to plop down a dispenser with a stack of red wool named "testa" and a stack of orange wool named "testb" already in the dispenser inventory. I've gotten everything but the name. The weird part is, the command below actually runs, no errors, but it generates a dispenser with a stack of red wool just named "red wool" and likewise for the orange stack.

```
/setblock ~-3 ~ ~ dispenser[facing=east]{Items:[{Slot:0,id:red_wool,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"testa"}}},{Slot:1,id:orange_wool,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"testb"}}}]} replace
```

Comment: Are you using Java or Bedrock?

Comment: @Penguin It’s safe to assume this player is on Java, notice how the command contains block states and NBT data, which is not possible on Bedrock.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 yes but he said it isnt working - one of those reasons would be copying from a java tutorial into bedrock

Comment: Oh wait i saw he said it placed with red wool nvm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft 1.13 display:{Name:""} NBT tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/minecraft-1-13-displayname-nbt-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You have to stringify (cancel out) the quotes around the names. You can do this with backslashes ("\"item_name\"") or by placing the double qoutes in a pair of single quotes ('"item_name"').

```
/setblock ~-3 ~ ~ dispenser[facing=east]{Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:red_wool",Count:64b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"testa\""}}},{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:orange_wool",Count:64b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"testb\""}}}]} replace
```