# How to give a player a named item with attributes using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to figure out how to give a player a named item with attributes using command blocks but every time I try it, there is either an error or it doesnt give the custom name.

My code that doesn't work:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers: 
[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage", slot:"mainhand", Amount:500, UUID:[I;1, 1, 1, 1,]}],
Unbreakable:1b, display:{Name:"epic sword"}} 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my item name not show up in 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/why-does-my-item-name-not-show-up-in-1-13)

Comment: I was expecting this to be a really interesting question, and was disappointed that it turned out to be another instance of something asked countless times before.