# Adding a name property to a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to add {name:"Rifle"} to this command:

```
/item replace entity pandafish321 hotbar.2 with minecraft:crossbow{ChargedProjectiles:[{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b}],Charged:1b}
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
 /item replace entity pandafish321 hotbar.2 with minecraft:crossbow{ChargedProjectiles:[{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b}],Charged:1b,display:{name:"Rifle"}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my item name not show up in 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334946/why-does-my-item-name-not-show-up-in-1-13)

Comment: Do not know if it makes a difference, but what version of Minecraft Java edition are you running?